# Expansion of the derivatives of the electric and magnetic fields

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, physics, fourier-series

I'm reading electrodynamics physics notes that describe a cavity of length $L$. The cavity is said to lie along the $z$-axis from $-L$ to $0$. The electric field is polarized in the $x$ direction and the magnetic field is polarized in the $y$ direction.

It then says that the basis functions for expansion of the electric and magnetic fields are

$$u_n(z) = \sin(k_n z) \ \ \ \ \ \ \text{and} \ \ \ \ \ \ v_n(z) = \cos(k_n z),$$

with

$$k_n = n \pi/L$$

These satisfy the relationship

$$\dfrac{\partial{u_n}(z)}{\partial{z}} = k_n v_n(z), \\ \dfrac{\partial{v_n}(z)}{\partial{z}} = -k_n u_n(z),$$
but are said to be "unnormalized" (I'm not totally sure what this means in this case).

It then says that fields in the cavity are expanded as

$$E(z, t) = \sum_n A_n(t) u_n(z), \\ H(z, t) = \sum_n H_n(t) v_n(z),$$
while the expansion of their derivatives follows from the above definitions to become

$$\begin{align*} \dfrac{\partial{E(z, t)}}{\partial{z}} &= \dfrac{2}{L} \sum_n v_n(z) \left( \int_{-L}^0 dz \ v_n(z) \dfrac{\partial{E(z, t)}}{\partial{z}} \right) \\ &= \sum_n v_n(z) \left( \dfrac{2}{L} E(0, t) + k_n A_n(t) \right), \end{align*}$$
$$\begin{align*} -\dfrac{\partial{H(z, t)}}{\partial{z}} &= \dfrac{-2}{L} \sum_n u_n(z) \left( \int_{-L}^0 dz \ u_n(z) \dfrac{\partial{H(z, t)}}{\partial{z}} \right) \\ &= \sum_n u_n(z) k_n H_n(t) \end{align*}$$

I don't understand how these last equations are derived. How does the expansion of the derivatives from the above definitions get us these equations?

---

### EDIT

I found something seemingly relevant during my research. The textbook *Complements of Higher Mathematics* by Andreas Echsner and Marin Marin says the following:

> In the following we will write the Fourier series for the periodical function having the particular period $2\pi$.
>
> **Theorem 4.1.3** *Consider a periodical function $f : [-\pi, \pi] \to R$ which has the period $T = 2\pi$. Then*
> *(i) if $f$ is an even function, then its Fourier series becomes*
> $$f(x) = \dfrac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx),$$
> *where*
> $$a_0 = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi f(x) \ dx, \ \ \ \ \ a_n = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi f(x) \cos(nx) \ dx.$$
> *(ii) if $f$ is an odd function, then its Fourier series becomes*
> $$f(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty b_n \sin(nx),$$
> *where*
> $$b_n = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi f(x) \sin(nx) \ dx$$

> **Remark.** It is usual to say that an even function has a Fourier's cosine series and an odd function has a Fourier's sine series.
> Now, we consider the case of the functions defined on a non-symmetrical interval of the form $[0, \pi]$.
>
> **Theorem 4.1.4** *Consider the function $f : [0, \pi] \to R$. Then it admits both a Fourier's cosine series and a Fourier's sine series.*
>
> *Proof* To find the Fourier's cosine series of the function, we construct the following function
> $$g(x) = \begin{cases} f(x), & x \in [0, \pi] \\ f(-x), & x \in [-\pi, 0]. \end{cases}$$
> It is a simple matter to verify that $g$ is an even function and then, according to the Theorem 4.1.3, it admits a cosine series
> $$g(x) = \dfrac{a_0}{2} + \sum_{n = 1}^\infty a_n \cos(nx),$$
> where
> $$a_0 = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi g(x) \ dx, \ \ \ \ \ a_n = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi g(x) \cos(nx) \ dx.$$
> But on the interval $[0, \pi]$ the function $g(x)$ is $f(x)$ such that the above series is, in fact, the series of function $f$.
> To find the Fourier's sine series of the function, we construct the following function
> $$h(x) = \begin{cases} f(x), & x \in [0, \pi] \\ -f(-x), & x \in [-\pi, 0]. \end{cases}$$
> It is a simple matter to verify that $h$ is an odd function and then, according to the Theorem 4.1.3, it admits a sine series
> $$h(x) = \sum_{n = 1}^\infty b_n \sin(nx),$$
> where
> $$b_n = \dfrac{2}{\pi} \int_0^\pi g(x) \sin(nx) \ dx.$$
> But on the interval $[0, \pi]$ the function $h(x)$ is $f(x)$ such that the above series is, in fact, the series of function $f$. So, the theorem is concluded.

If someone would please help me put this all together in the context of my question, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: The first equality is simply the Fourier expansion. The second follows from taking the derivative with respect to $z$ of the corresponding expansion and using orthogonality properties.

Comment: @Dog_69 Thanks for clarifying. I'd appreciate it if someone would please show how this is derived step-by-step, so that I can clearly see.

Comment: If you believe the first equality, take the series expansion of each field, compute the derivative and replace what you get in the integral (it'll be an infinite sum). Assuming you can commute the integral with the sum, and you can, integrate each term. You'll need some orthogonality properties of sines and cosines. I'm on my phone and it's annoying to type a full answer with so many maths symbols.

Comment: @Dog_69 I briefly studied some Fourier series a while ago, but I never spent enough time to study/learn it properly. Now that you mention it, from what I remember, the $\dfrac{2}{L}$ factor is a familiar aspect of Fourier series, and I also remember that there was some orthogonality stuff between the $\sin$ and $\cos$ terms of the Fourier series and something to do with taking the inner product. But I really don't remember the details of how this stuff is done, so it's probably better that I just wait for an answer so that I can clearly see.

Comment: Fourier expansion is about writing a function in terms of sines and cosines. The integral you see is the way the coefficients are computed. Due to physical reasons I don't know, your electric field is an odd function, and so only needs sines. The magnetic field however is even, so only cosines appear. Coefficients are computed in that way because you're projecting onto each of the components. The formalism behind is that of vector spaces, but in this case it's of infinite dimension and the scalar (dot) product is the integral...

Comment: ... You can find more more about that searching for L^2 spaces and Hilbert spaces (the former is a particular case of the later).  Wikipedia should be a good source. Regarding the normalisation of the u's and v's that you mention, it precisely means that, although they provide an orthogonal basis for the spaces, they are not normal (unitary norm or unitary scalar product with themselves).

Comment: @Dog_69 thanks for the additional clarification. Any chance you could post an answer?

Comment: There are not many things to add, except that for the case of the electric field, you first use integration by parts. I encourage you to write your own answer

Comment: @Dog_69 Feel free to post an answer. I'm clearly not understanding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's see if the following helps.

First, we don't need to worry about the expansions of $E$ and $H$ themselves; we are told they exist and are of the form

$$
E(z,t)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty A_n(t) \sin(k_nz) \\
H(z,t)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty H_n(t) \cos(k_n z),
$$

whatever the coefficients $A_n(t)$ and $H_n(t)$ are (they have been computed using the formulas you mention).

Now, we want to expand their derivatives. Let's start with the electric field:

$$
\frac{\partial E(t,z)}{\partial z} = \frac{B_0(t)}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n(t)\cos (k_n z),
$$

(the electric field is odd, so its derivative is even, thus the cosines)
where the coefficients $B_n(t)$ are computed as we know (as the theorem you have posted tells us):

$$
B_n(t)=\frac{2}{L} \int_{-L}^0 \frac{\partial E(t,z)}{\partial z}  \cos (k_nz)
 dz.$$

I mean $B_n(t)$ and not $A_n(t)$  because, for the momment, we are expanding $\partial E/\partial z$ as if we knew nothing about $E(t,z)$. Suppose that $\partial E/\partial z$ is a function $f(t,z)$ and we expand it.

For $n\neq 0$, the integral above is computed by parts:

$$ \int_{-L}^0 \frac{\partial E(t,z)}{\partial z}  \cos (k_nz)
 dz= E(t,z)\cos(k_nz)\bigg|_{-L}^0 - \int_{-L}^0 E(t,z)\frac{d}{dz}\cos(k_n z)= E(t,z)\cos(k_nz)\bigg|_{-L}^0 +  \sum_{m=0}^\infty k_n\int_{-L}^0 A_n(t)\sin(k_m z) (z,t)\sin(k_nz)dz =  E(t,z)\cos(k_nz)\bigg|_{-L}^0 - A_n(t)k_n\frac{L}{2}
$$

(you can see the computations [here ($m\neq n$)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+%5BSin%5B+m+Pi+z%2FL%5DSin%5Bn+Pi+z%2FL%5D%2C%7Bz%2C-L%2C0%7D%5D) and [here ($m=n$)](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+%5BSin%5B+n+Pi+z%2FL%5DSin%5Bn+Pi+z%2FL%5D%2C%7Bz%2C-L%2C0%7D%5D), so that it results:

$$B_n(t)= \frac{2}{L}\left(E(t,z)\cos(k_nz)\bigg|_{-L}^0 + k_n\frac{L}{2}\right).
$$

Now let's compute $B_0$:

$$
B_0(t)=\frac{2}{L}\int_{-L}^0 \frac{\partial E(t,z)}{\partial z}dz = \sum_{n=0}^\infty k_n \int_{-L}^0 A_n(t)\cos(n\pi z/L)dz = 0
$$

(answer [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+%5BCos%28n+%CF%80+z%2FL%29%2C%7Bz%2C-L%2C0%7D%5D).

Hence:

$$
\frac{\partial E(t,z)/\partial z} = \frac{B_0(t)}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^\infty B_n(t)\cos(n\pi z/L) =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2}{L}\left(E(t,z)\cos(k_nz)\bigg|_{-L}^0 + k_n\frac{L}{2}\right)\cos(n\pi z/L). $$

There is one missing detail, something I do not really understand. For $n>0$, the result for $B_n(t)$ involves  $E(0,t)$ and $E(t,-L)\cos(-n\pi)$.
If we use the series to compute $E(t,-L)$, we get a zero, so that term vanishes, so it would not appear in the final expression, that is OK. But the same should happen to $E(t,0)$.
So check the boundary conditions and see what the values of  $E(t,0)$ and  $E(t,-L)$ are.

The magnetic field seems to follow the same procedure, although you can check that the result is exactly the same as if we computed the derivative $\partial H/\partial z$ directly. Be careful because in doing so we are igonoring the boundary conditions at $z=0,-L$.
Compute $\partial H/\partial z$ using both approaches and check that indeed they agree.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post an answer. I really cannot follow what you've written here. I wrote $$E(z, t) = \sum_n A_n(t) u_n(z),$$ but you've written $$\frac{\partial E(t,z)}{\partial z} = -\frac{2}{L}B_n(t)\cos (k_n z)$$ and $$B_n(t)=\int_{-L}^0 \frac{\partial E(t,z)}{\partial z}  \cos (k_nz)  dz.$$ Please clarify.

Comment: @ThePointer. It's my pleasure. There are actually some mistakes in my answer. It's not possible for me to correct them now, but I will in the next 24h or so, trying to address the questions you've mentioned in your comments. Happy new year!

Comment: Thanks for that. Happy new year to you too. I will expand on my points of confusion for when you're able to provide clarification. I have tried many times to write this out myself, but I am having trouble with both the calculations for the electric field and magnetic field. [...]

Comment: One point is that, as you said in one of your comments, the electric field $$E(z, t) = \sum_n A_n(t) u_n(z)$$ is an odd function, and so only has sines. But you then use $$\frac{\partial E(t,z)}{\partial z} = -\frac{2}{L}B_n(t)\cos (k_n z)$$ and $$B_n(t)=\int_{-L}^0 \frac{\partial E(t,z)}{\partial z}  \cos (k_nz)  dz,$$ which use cosines. So that is a point of confusion for me.

Comment: Furthermore, I don't understand why $$\frac{\partial E(t,z)}{\partial z} = -\frac{2}{L}B_n(t)\cos (k_n z)$$ has a negative sign in it. My understanding is that, since the period is of length $L$, should it not just be $\dfrac{2}{L}$ instead of $\dfrac{2}{-L}$?

Comment: Another big point of confusion for me when writing this out is what is happening to all of the $k_n$ factors from differentiating $\sin(k_n z)$ and $\cos(k_n z)$. By the chain rule, we get that $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\sin(k_n z) = k_n \cos(k_n z)$ and $\dfrac{\partial}{\partial{z}}\cos(k_n z) = -k_n \sin(k_n z)$. But in both the original calculations and in yours, there is an absence of these $k_n$ factors from differentiating the $\sin(k_n z)$ and $\cos(k_n z)$.

Comment: If you would please write out the full details of the calculations for both the magnetic field and electric field, I would greatly appreciate it. There seems to be a lot of small things that aren't clear without full calculations, so I think that would clear up a lot of the confusion for me. Thanks again.